# DNS SERVFAIL and NXDOMAIN on specific hostname

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I have two DNS servers in my domain, Windows 2003 and Windows 2008, but recently both are failing to route users to www.cdw.com. I have had no other complaints with any other websites, but when trying to use cdw.com the page never loads. I tried to resolve the hostname and get the NXDOMAIN error below:

```
MyComputer:~ me$ nslookup cdw.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.2.1, trying next server
Server:     192.168.2.2
Address:    192.168.2.2#53

** server can't find cdw.com: NXDOMAIN

MyComputer:~ me$ nslookup serverfault.com
Server:     192.168.2.2
Address:    192.168.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 198.252.206.16
```

Comment: Seeing as your DNS servers aren't authoritative for the cdw.com domain name, what do you have set up in the way of Forwarders? Do you have Forwarders configured or are you using the root hint server only?

Comment: @joeqwerty root hints only (ie. a.root-servers.net, etc.)

Comment: @joeqwerty if I use GoogleDNS for forwarder the name resolves, but not using root hints... weird. :(